# Database error when installing Akeneo PIM

Tags: installation, akeneo

I am trying to install Akeneo PIM, according to the installation instructions on this page. [Installing Akeneo PIM Community Edition (CE) with the Archive](https://docs.akeneo.com/latest/install_pim/manual/installation_ce_archive.html)

When I run the following command:

`bin/console pim:install --force --symlink --clean --env=prod`

I get an error:

```
Database does not exist yet
06:21:53 ERROR     [console] Error thrown while running command "doctrine:database:create --no-debug=1 --env=prod". Message: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" ["exception" => Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException { …},"command" => "doctrine:database:create --no-debug=1 --env=prod","message" => "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory"]

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or dir  
  ectory                                                                       


In PDOConnection.php line 50:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  


In PDOConnection.php line 46:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  


doctrine:database:create [--shard SHARD] [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>

The command terminated with an error code: 1.

In CommandExecutor.php line 66:

  The command terminated with an error code: 1.  


doctrine:database:create [--shard SHARD] [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

Then I created a database in MySQL. And added database connection information to the `~/pim-community-standard/app/config/parameters.yml.dist` file.

**~/pim-community-standard/app/config/parameters.yml.dist:**

```
parameters:
    database_driver:                      pdo_mysql
    database_host:                        127.0.0.1
    database_port:                        null
    database_name:                        akeneo_pim
    database_user:                        root
    database_password:                    root
```

But I still get the same error.

*I think there's a missing configuration. But i can not found.*

Comment: **Problem is solved:**
No need to make any changes to the `~/pim-community-standard/app/config/parameters.yml.dist` file. I just created MySQL database as described on this page. [Installation — Akeneo PIM documentation](https://docs.akeneo.com/1.3/developer_guide/installation/installation_workstation.html#mysql)